# Extract minutes and seconds (ex '02m12s') from YouTube URL param

Tags: php, regex, string, youtube

Best way to extract the minutes and seconds from youtube urls?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjTbNWhsG28#t=1m40s&foo=1&bar=2

where `1m40s` is the string i need and either '#t=' or '&t=' may be used.

could be at the end too (or in middle but unlikely. i will rule that one out)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjTbNWhsG28?foo=1&bar=2#t=1m40s

'x' in 'xmxs' can be a one or two digit number and only one of them might be passed

"#t=10m3s" or 
 "&t=09m12s"

and they are each optional as in

"#t=10m" or 
 "&t=3s" or
 "#t=10m03"s

YouTube now accepts '#t=' as well as '&t=' for this param so ideally I need to consider both. Users will be pasting these into the comments section of a blog and the output generates the embed. The script I am currently using does not parse these time values.

Once I know the minutes and seconds I will pass the total seconds on to the script that generates embed code using the 'start' param.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#start

I need a PHP solution. I assume a nice combination of `substr()` and regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjTbNWhsG28#t=40m&foo=1&bar=2";
$regex_pattern1 = "([#|\&]+t+\=+[0-9]+[m]+[0-9]+[s])"; // minutes and seconds
$regex_pattern2 = "([#|\&]+t+\=+[0-9]+[m])"; // only minutes
$regex_pattern3 = "([#|\&]+t+\=+[0-9]+[s])"; // only seconds
$pattern_used = null;
if(!preg_match_all($regex_pattern1, $url, $time)) // not found "#t=XmXs"
{
    if(!preg_match_all($regex_pattern2, $url, $time)) // not found "#t=Xm"
    {
        if(!preg_match_all($regex_pattern3, $url, $time)) // not found "#t=Xs"
            die("Invalid URL");
        else $pattern_used = 3;
    }   
    else $pattern_used = 2;
}
else $pattern_used = 1;
$time = substr($time[0][0], 3, strlen($time[0][0])); // deleting "#t="

//echo $time; // prints "1m40s" or "40s" if only seconds are given

// --------------
$pattern_minutes = "([0-9]+[s])";
$pattern_seconds = "([0-9]+[m])";
if($pattern_used == 1) // we have both minutes and seconds defined
{
    $minutes = preg_split($pattern_minutes, $time);
    $seconds = preg_split($pattern_seconds, $time);

    $array = array("minutes" => substr($minutes[0], 0, -1), 
                   "seconds" => substr($seconds[1], 0, -1));

    /* we have the following array now:
    array (size=2)
        'minutes' => string '1' (length=1)
        'seconds' => string '40' (length=2)*/
}
else
{
    if($pattern_used == 2) $time2 = preg_split($pattern_minutes, $time);
    else $time2 = preg_split($pattern_seconds, $time); 
    $time2 = substr($time2[0], 0, -1);
    echo $time2; // prints "40"
}
```

Comment: you miss `#t=10m` and `&t=3s`

Comment: @burning_LEGION I think it's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks! But the regex doesn't seem to work when only minute or second is passed. As I mentioned above sometimes only one will be in the url: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjTbNWhsG28#t=4s&foo=1&bar=2

Comment: The other thing is just splitting the two values so I can convert them to seconds. What would be the best way to say convert 1m40s into an array like array('m' => 1, 's'=> 40), again with the condition that only one might be passed in the original string.

Comment: Thanks! So close! I think it still fails in the case of minutes but no seconds, no? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjTbNWhsG28#t=1m&foo=1&bar=2

Answer (score 3):

use this regex `((#)|(\&))t=(\d+m)?(\d+s)?`

Comment: `Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 't' in C:\wamp\www\php\yturl.php on line 6`

Comment: @Nikola K., `t` is is simply symbol in string, may be you lost shield?

Comment: the regex is right, but i don`t know php to help with this warning

Comment: Enclose the regex in a delimiter, e.g., `@((#)|(\&))t=(\d+m)?(\d+s)?@`.

Answer (score 3):

I find the code of the accepted answer quite messy. It also not covers hours. Also I think YouTube Dropped the `#` URLs. I have code this function inside my [Advanced Responsive Video Embedder](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-responsive-video-embedder/) WordPress plugin. I think it's pretty clean coded and way easier to understand compared to the accepted answer.

I hope this will help somebody.

**Updated 2019 notice the (int) part strips out the h/m/s characters.** I am open for suggestions to improve.

```
/**
 * Calculates seconds based on youtube times
 *
 * @author    Nicolas Jonas
 * @license   GPLv3
 * @link      http://nextgenthemes.com
 *
 * @param     string $yttime   The '1h25m13s' part of youtube URLs
 *
 * @return    int   Starttime in seconds
 */
function youtube_time_to_seconds( $yttime ) {

    $matches['h'] = 0;
    $matches['m'] = 0;
    $matches['s'] = 0;

    $pattern = '/' .
        '(?<h>[0-9]+h)?' .
        '(?<m>[0-9]+m)?' .
        '(?<s>[0-9]+s)?/';

    preg_match( $pattern, $yttime, $matches );

    return ( (int) $matches['h'] * 60 * 60 ) +
        ( (int) $matches['m'] * 60 ) +
        (int) $matches['s'];
}
```

Old code for ref. Does not account for cases 1h2s:

```
/**
 * Calculates seconds based on youtube times
 *
 * @author    Nicolas Jonas
 * @license   GPLv3
 * @link      http://nextgenthemes.com
 *
 * @param     string $yttime   The '1h25m13s' part of youtube URLs
 *
 * @return    int   Starttime in seconds
 */
function youtube_time_to_seconds( $yttime ) {

    $format = false;
    $hours  = $minutes = $seconds = 0;

    $pattern['hms'] = '/([0-9]+)h([0-9]+)m([0-9]+)s/'; // hours, minutes, seconds
    $pattern['ms']  =          '/([0-9]+)m([0-9]+)s/'; // minutes, seconds
    $pattern['h']   = '/([0-9]+)h/';
    $pattern['m']   = '/([0-9]+)m/';
    $pattern['s']   = '/([0-9]+)s/';

    foreach ( $pattern as $k => $v ) {

        preg_match( $v, $yttime, $result );

        if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
            $format = $k;
            break;
        }
    }

    switch ( $format ) {
        case 'hms':
            $hours   = $result[1];
            $minutes = $result[2];
            $seconds = $result[3];
            break;
        case 'ms':
            $minutes = $result[1];
            $seconds = $result[2];
            break;
        case 'h':
            $hours = $result[1];
            break;
        case 'm':
            $minutes = $result[1];
            break;
        case 's':
            $seconds = $result[1];
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    return ( $hours * 60 * 60 ) + ( $minutes * 60 ) + $seconds;
}
```

Source: [Github](https://github.com/nextgenthemes/advanced-responsive-video-embedder/blob/master/public/class-advanced-responsive-video-embedder-public.php#L1664-L1716)

One could use it like this:

It parses the URL and parameters with `parse_url` and `parse_str` instead of regexing entire URLS that is the better and more reliable way to do this.

```
$urls[] = 'http://youtu.be/vrXgLhkv21Y';
$urls[] = 'http://youtu.be/vrXgLhkv21Y?t=foobar';
$urls[] = 'http://youtu.be/vrXgLhkv21Y?foo=bar&t=4s';
$urls[] = 'http://youtu.be/vrXgLhkv21Y?t=1h19m14s';
$urls[] = 'http://youtu.be/vrXgLhkv21Y?t=19m14s';
$urls[] = 'http://youtu.be/vrXgLhkv21Y?t=2h';
$urls[] = 'http://youtu.be/vrXgLhkv21Y?t=5m';
$urls[] = 'http://youtu.be/vrXgLhkv21Y?t=50s';

#extract the part after the &t= in urls and run the function if exists 
foreach( $urls as $url ) {

    $parsed_url = parse_url( $url );

    if ( empty( $parsed_url['query'] ) )
        continue;

    parse_str( $parsed_url['query'], $args );

    if ( empty( $args['t'] ) )
        continue;

    echo youtube_time_to_seconds( $args['t'] ) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
4
4754
1154
7200
300
50
```

Comment: This is good, but you're missing the case where the time is in `hm` or `hs` formats (e.g: 1h1m, 1h10s, both valid.) you can use a single pattern for preg_match: `'/([0-9]+h)?([0-9]+m)?([0-9]+s)?/'` to capture the hours/minutes/seconds. e.g.: `$hours   = array_key_exists( 1, $result ) ? $result[1] : 0;`.

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert You are right, I added a new even simpler function without any use of `array_key_exists`.